# Converting a timer formatted as "Minutes:Seconds:Milliseconds" to a total millisecond count

Tags: javascript, math, formula, operation

Here's the scenario: I have a running timer that I'm displaying on my page, and a textarea with some functionality piped in to allow users to hit keyboard shortcuts in order to auto populate the time at which they hit the key into the textarea. For example, if the user presses CMD+1 when the timer is at 00:21:30, the textarea autofills with "00:21:30 - Good Take" on the active line.

Here's the simple timer and formatting code I'm using:

```
export const formatMinutes = (time: number): string => {
  return ('0' + Math.floor((time / 60000) % 60)).slice(-2);
}

export const formatSeconds = (time: number): string => {
  return ('0' + Math.floor((time / 1000) % 60)).slice(-2);
}

export const formatMilliseconds = (time: number): string => {
  return ('0' + ((time / 10) % 100)).slice(-2);
}

useEffect(() => {
  let interval = null;
  if (timerRunning) {
    interval = setInterval(() => {
      setTime((prev) => prev + 10);
    }, 10);
  } else {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, [timerRunning]);

const mins = formatMinutes(time);
const secs = formatSeconds(time);
const millisecs = formatMilliseconds(time);
const timecode = `${mins}:${secs}:${millisecs}`;
```

This all works as I want it to. What I need to do now is, after a user clicks a button, parse the textarea for all of the timestamped notes and convert those timestamps *back to their original numeric value* so that I can then convert them to a frame count and pipe them into an XML file as markers for Premiere.

Math was never my strong suit so I'm having trouble figuring out how to take the string timestamp of XX:XX:XX and covert it back into the number it was originally derived from. Could any mathematically minded folks give me a hand?

Comment: `mins * 60 * 1000 + secs * 1000 + milisecs`

Comment: You may not want to rely on the textarea to provide backing storage for your data.  I mean, it's not that it can't work like that, but it's just as easy to push your timestamps into a JavaScript array and keep them there.  I guess it only matters if you want to permit the user to edit the timestamp data in the textarea - then you'd actually need to parse it again.

Comment: @Wyck we're doing more than just storing the data there - we're using it as a free text space for note taking and editing, allowing users to inject the timecodes into preexisting documents and adjust the stamps themselves manually if necessary, so unfortunately it's not as easy as just storying them in an array.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is just how to "HH:MM:SS" => "Miliseconds", then:

```
const answer = (str: string) => {
  const [hh, mm, ss] = str.split(':').map((str) => +str);
  const seconds = hh * 3600 + mm * 60 + ss;

  return seconds * 1000;
};
```